# How do I deploy a custom app to my iPhone?

Tags: applications, iphone, xcode

I'm taking a mobile phone app development class, and will be making custom apps using Xcode.  I'm able to run the app from Xcode on my iPhone 4 no problem, however when I disconnect the phone from the Mac, I'm unable to run the program anymore.  I'm wondering how install the app so that I can run it.

Comment: Are you running your app in the Xcode simulator, or running in your iPhone 4.  Without the $99 developer subscriber, I don't think you can deploy your app to your iPhone.  Unless your iPhone is jail breaked.

Comment: @kukoo The iPhone isn't jail broken but I'm using the schools certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the schools certificate is sufficient to deploy the app on the device.  After turning off the simulator, or simply unplugging the device from the machine, the application will stay on the device for further use.  There is no further configuration that needs to be done.  However, you will not be able to deploy the app to the store UNLESS you have the rights to do so (which most students do not).

Answer (score 6):

You are required to possess the $99/yr developer account with Apple. Without it, you'll lack the sufficient certificates to have the app permanently installed on your device.

Answer (score 3):

The school certificate allows you to develop your app and test it on your iOS devices, however, you are not allowed to publish your app into the iOS App Store, therefore, you are not able to keep it on your device without the Xcode. You need the $99/yr developer account